# SSL certificate problem when trying to open GeoJSON file

Tags: geojson, qgis-2.18

I'm getting the following error when trying to open a GeoJSON file in QGIS:

> Data source is invalid (SSL certificate problem: self signed
>   certificate in certificate chain)

Is this related to the page being https?  Is there a workaround to get the file downloaded locally?  I found a couple mentions of it possibly being a bug but no solution was given.  Normally I remove the 's' to make it unsecured and it works but in this instance it won't allow me.

[Query page](https://app.mdt.mt.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Standard/Reference_Markers_Labeled/MapServer)

[Query result](https://app.mdt.mt.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Standard/Reference_Markers_Labeled/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=geojson)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the following solution:

Firstly, I added the below variables within QGIS -> Settings ->Options- > System-> Environment section. (It wasn't any immediate effect), but then I added them at System environmental variables (at OS system properties):

Variable Name: GDAL_HTTP_USERAGENT

Variable Value: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36

Variable Name: GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL

Variable Value: YES

Restart QGIS and them try to add the GeoJSON file link again.

Comment: This solution is same as using http directly as topicstarter wrote. You only disable secure in https.

Comment: This worked, the key is adding the OS system environmental variables as well.  Thanks Ioana.

Answer (score 0):

I can run the query for layer "reference markers" on your page, I can't replicate the error, this is the url that points to the
    [geojson](http://I%20can%20make%20the%20query%20for%20the%20layer%20%22reference%20markers%22,%20can't%20replicate%20your%20error;%20this%20is%20the%20geojson%20the%20query%20points%20to:%20https://app.mdt.mt.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Standard/Reference_Markers_Labeled/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=geojson)
that's generated from the query (you may Add-vector-layer>>protocol>>url in QGIS) is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I can run the query, I can't get it to load in QGIS.  Your link is invalid by the way.

Answer (score -1):

Try alternative [installer](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/) of QGIS by NextGIS. This problem occurs in QGIS from qgis.org because of outdated **openssl** library. In NextGIS installer most of libraries are up to date.

Also you may see [blogpost](http://nextgis.com/blog/qgis17/) about new installer.

Comment: I was hoping for at least a workaround instead of buying software.

Comment: It's **free**. No need to buy anything exists in normal QGIS. Also you can install NextGIS QGIS near the QGIS. They not conflicting.